# How to determine if all entries of a `.bib` file have been used

Tags: bibliographies

I have compiled a large but relevant literature list in a `.bib` file.
Now I want to make sure, that *all* references are cited in my final PDF.

How could I achieve this?
Should I loop over all "@" entries in the `.bib` file and do a `grep -ir` in all my `.tex` files?
Or is there an easier way?

Comment: use a numbered bib style and check that the number of the last entry matches the number of entries in your bib (and don't use `\nocite`)

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the most robust and fastest variant, but if each entry is specified by

```
@book{ENTRY,
```

or

```
@article{ENTRY,
```

this will report if all literature was cited at least once (Well... actually if all bibtex entries have been found in the tex file, which is in my case a safe assumption):

```
#!/bin/bash

numMatches=0
bibFile=foo.bib # bibliography
allEntries=$(grep '@' $bibFile | wc -l)
texFiles=Chapters/*.tex # file glob for all .tex files

for entry in $(grep '@' $bibFile); do 
   item=$(sed 's/.*{//; s/,$//' <<< ${entry##@});
   [[ ! -z $(grep -ir "$item" $texFiles) ]] && numMatches=$((numMatches+1))
done

if (( $numMatches != $allEntries )); then
   echo "Not all literature cited."
else
   echo "All literature cited."
fi
```

Comment: I'm curious how this works.  I can't find anything about an `ENTRY` field, and don't know enough bash to understand.

Comment: @Teepeemm, basically this filters the bibliography file for lines containing the `@` symbol, which might be `@article`, `@book`, etc. For each match I do search for the entry in any `.tex` files, if it matches at least once, the entry was used as a reference. In the end I simply count the matches, and if they do not equate all entries in the bibliography file (lines with `@`) I conclude that not all references had been used. Definitely not a very elegant solution, but should work.

Comment: Ok.  I thought when you wrote `@book{ENTRY`, you meant to add an `ENTRY` field, which doesn't seem to exist.  It seems like you are actually intending `ENTRY` to refer to the citation key, so that your first condition ("if each entry is specified by") automatically happens for a proper bib file.  That means that the real magic of this solution is using bash to take the entries from the bib file and grep through the tex files for them.  +1.